# Is such manned flight feasible?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

We all know that manpower hydrofoils can fly over calm water. here

[Hydrofoil Surface Flight](https://youtu.be/WszbRFF_WLk)

So is the manpower aircraft in the link below feasible?

[Manpower flight](https://youtu.be/uS-JLuLIQ6Q)

I think this kind of manned aircraft is feasible, as long as the area and lift center are well controlled.

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? Please don't just post links for others to follow; add images or more descriptive text to your question so that all needed information is here in one place.

Comment: @hazzey I'm thinking of adding some information.

Comment: Don't waste your time adding more information.
There is no reason to think about a manpowered aicraft. 
They work but are pretty much useless. They are just like any other unpowered aircraft but just with a tiny amount of extra power ...

Comment: @DanielH. So why are people still studying paper airplanes?

Comment: @enbin zhang people are still trying to build 
perpetual motion machines even though it's nonsense. 

Just build that thing and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There are untold numbers of fake videos circulating on the internet. This site does not aim to debunk them. The burden of plausibility is upon the asker.

Comment: I guess the question here is, can the operator as shown in the second video exert *any* propelling force on the aircraft? I suspect that they can. I think it will be almost nothing, but maybe in zero g environment it might work.

Comment: @DanielH. So why can he fly on the water?

Comment: @user16 The video of flying over the water must be true.

Comment: @Drew How could the first person "fly" on the water?  How did he push his "aircraft"?

Answer (score 2):

The video shows a human bean on a hydrofoil wake board or small surfboard using inertia to propel the board and passenger forward. The mass of the board is small compared to the human and the viscosity of the water is high compared to that of air. The foils are substantially smaller in proportion to those of an aircraft.

The aircraft mass will be substantially greater than the human if it is capable of flight with such a payload.

Consider also the plight of the wind-up flying toy bird. It's much lighter than a person and has a greater power-to-weight ratio (rubber band versus muscle) than a person. It does fly, but only barely.

Comment: "a human bean" - +1 for typo. I'm not sure whether surfers are wannabeans or hasbeans, though.

Comment: not a typo. I like the expression.

Comment: @fred_dot_u ，This person also exerted force to push himself forward.

Answer (score 1):

Unpowered heavier-than-air machines for human flight have been around for a long time.

Official endurance records for gliders (sailplanes) were abandoned long ago, since the only thing being measured was the ability of the pilot to stay awake and still be in a fit mental state to make a controlled landing at the end of the flight. The last official record, a flight of just over 71 hours (almost 3 days), was made over 60 years ago.

Just throw away the "surfboard," and redesign the rest of the structure to make it more aerodynamic!

Comment: This aircraft is not powerless, but powered by human power.